# SQL Query for joining non existent rows with a NULL field

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join, ifnull

I have 2 tables

```
A. LinkNames

LINKID NAME
1  Name1
2  Name2
3  Name3

B. Links

WebsiteID  LINKID  LINKPATH
1             1     "WWW.test.com"
```

I need a query that displays output like this

```
LINKID   LINKNAME   LINKPATH
1         NAME1     WWW.test.com
2         NAME2     ""
3         NAME3     ""
```

I have tried all the possible joins but not coming through

Answer (score 2):

Use **LEFT JOIN** to join bothe tables.

Try this:

```
SELECT A.LINKID, 
       A.NAME AS LINKNAME, 
       IFNULL(B.LINKPATH, '""') AS LINKPATH
FROM LinkNames A
LEFT JOIN Links B ON A.LINKID = B.LINKID;
```

If you want to put `WebSiteID = 1` condition then use below query:

```
SELECT A.LINKID, 
       A.NAME AS LINKNAME, 
       IFNULL(B.LINKPATH, '""') AS LINKPATH
FROM LinkNames A
LEFT JOIN Links B ON A.LINKID = B.LINKID AND B.WebsiteID = 1;
```

Above query will allow NULL values also.

Comment: This query works well but as soon as I put a where clause SELECT A.LINKID, A.NAME AS LINKNAME, IFNULL(B.LINKPATH, '""') AS LINKPATH
FROM LinkNames A
LEFT JOIN Links B ON A.LINKID = B.LINKID WHERE WebsiteID  = 1 this does not show the null rows.... Apologies for missing that out in the initial question

Comment: Thanks a ton:) This works .. I have been struggling since 2 days on this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `INNER JOIN`  like below

```
SELECT LinkNames.LINKID,
       LinkNames.NAME,
       Links.LINKPATH
FROM LinkNames
JOIN Links ON LinkNames.LINKID = Links.LINKID ;
```